# Scrolling Colorbox in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, colorbox

I'm using [ColorBox's](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)  Ajax mode.

```
<a class='data-content' href='data/<?=$id?>'> <img src=uploads/thumb_<?=$img?> /> </a>

     <script type="text/javascript"> 

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".data-content").colorbox({
              transition: "none",
              title: false,
              width: "700px",
              top: "10px",
              loop: false,
              scrolling: false
        });

      });

     </script>
```

After clicking on photo thumb it loads colorbox with photo and other content. Usually it's height is larger than screen. So scrollbars appear. With other browsers (Mozilla, Chrome) I can scroll up and down and see all content in box with no problems.

When scrolling with IE8 colorbox stays in the same place and instead that background scrolls. So I can't see all content.

Here is an [example](http://fotoplunksna.lt/colorbox/example2/). Actually it's the default Colorbox example.

Any ideas on what may be causing the problem?

Comment: not sure if this is the cause but your '<img src=uploads/thumb_<?=$img?> />'  has no quotes around the url i.e. src='uploads/thumb_<?=$img?>'

Comment: Thanks for quick coment, but it's not the cause. It's just shorten code and it works ok on site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved with new colorbox [update](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/commit/953bc129e765ddadfb3dd170a85ee41c16405095):

Thank you @Jack.

Answer (score 2):

It could be this... from the site - http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/#doctype

> ColorBox requires a valid doctype and
>   rendering in quirks mode is not
>   supported. If you aren't using the
>   HTML5 doctype, make sure you are using
>   the full doctype declaration (with
>   URI) to insure rendering in standards
>   mode.
>
> Unfortunately, this abbreviated
>   doctype renders the document in quirks
>   mode for Internet Explorer:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

> The doctype with URI renders in
>   standards mode for all browsers:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't help in my case. here is my doctype: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how that is possible unless you have some CSS that is setting colorbox's position to 'fixed'.  I suggest posting a link that demonstrates the problem.  Your code snippet looks fine, and using your same settings cause no issues for me when using colorbox for ajax content.

Comment: I posted a link to example in my question.